# Errors installing Oracle 19 on Windows 11 Business

Tags: oracle

I'm trying to install Oracle 19.30.00 on a brand new Windows 11 Business machine.
I tried several times choosing a different user to run the Oracle service (virtual, built-in, create new) but every time the installer failed with a different error (unable to set ACLs, etc).

I was running setup.bat "as Administrator".
After every install attempt/failure system is completely cleaned up (registry, users, inventory in Program Files) so this seems to be something not too obvious.

The last attempt I made was with virtual user as an Oracle service user option selected. The error was
[image]

```
INFO:  [Sep 1, 2023 12:08:19 PM] Skipping line: DIM-00019: create service error'
INFO:  [Sep 1, 2023 12:08:19 PM] O/S-Error: (OS 1387) A member could not be added to or removed from the local group because the member does not exist.
INFO:  [Sep 1, 2023 12:08:19 PM] Skipping line: O/S-Error: (OS 1387) A member could not be added to or removed from the local group because the member does not exist.
INFO:  [Sep 1, 2023 12:08:20 PM] Skipping line: 9% complete
INFO:  [Sep 1, 2023 12:08:20 PM] [FATAL] ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
INFO:  [Sep 1, 2023 12:08:20 PM] Skipping line: [FATAL] ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
```

I can see two problems here: one with a member and local group, and the other with TNS:protocol adapter error. Not sure if these issues are related or not.

Regards,
Valery

Comment: Have you read the log file?

Comment: What is Windows 11 Business? I've not heard of that edition. Also, what do the logs show?